# CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'tempdb'

Tags: sql-server, create-table

First time I installed SQL Server Management Studio Express and Visual Studio 2005 on my system. Now I am trying to create table by using below script. But if once I execute I am facing error like

> CREATE TABLE permission denied in
>   database 'tempdb'.

Why it it? Can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
([FirstName] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [LastName] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Thanks
Raju

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My initial guess is you do not have CREATE table rights on this server. Can you please run these set of queries below?

```
-- get login first 
select suser_name() 
--or 
SELECT SYSTEM_USER

-- Now get the permissions assigned to you by the server administrator 
use tempDB 
GO 

;with getPermissions as ( SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE') ) 
select permission_name from getPermissions 
where permission_name like 'create%' 
GO
```

If permission_name column returns 0 rows then it means you do not have CREATE permission on this DB. contact your DBA to grant db_ddladmin for tempDB. However as Andomar noted the temp tables are automatically created in tempDB when pre-appended with #.

Comment: Dear Ram,Thank you very much for your reply. I run your commands on my system . As you said it returns o rows.It means there is no permission.

Comment: I found solution like this. Actually I am using Windows vista so I started SQL SEVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO EXPRESS as a administrator by right clicking on that icon. So it worked fine.

Answer (score 32):

I went into the database, security, users, right-click on the user, properties.
Membership, checked db_owner.

Comment: This is a better answer because I was looking for the role that was less than sysadmin (what everyone else was suggesting on other questions).  I had dbcreator, but I forgot about db_owner.

Comment: Perfect!  Lots of choices in Membership to control access.  Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

```
Use tempdb
GO
Create User MyUserName For Login MyUserName with Default_Schema= [dbo];
go
use tempdb
go
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_ddladmin', N'MyUserName'
go
```

You need db_ddladmin role for the intended user to create a new table. so db_datawriter role wouldn't be enough.

Answer (score 12):

You're trying to create a permanent table in `tempdb`.  That's rather unusual, tempdb is completely wiped out whenever the SQL Server service restarts.

The normal way to create a temporary table is:

```
create table #TempTable (...
```

The `#` makes it a local (connection-specific) temporary table.  A global temporary table starts with `##`.  No special rights are required to create a temporary table this way.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem too. Searched for it, most of the answers were of db_owner, checked that too in Security menu item, but it was not being shown. While searching i went to [this](https://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/set-up-installation/create-table-permission-denied-in-database) blog. **Ivan Dimitrov**'s  answer gave me a bit hint. My create table query was:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Album](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[TrackCount] [int] NULL,
[ReleaseYear] [int] NULL,
[Distributor] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[ImageUrl] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Album] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I removed the **[dbo].** from the query and then ran it, executed successfully. Maybe it is not a complete solution but i managed to work with it somehow.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this answer will be helpful, but I experienced a similar problem and this is how I solved it. The issue I was experiencing was due to the fact that my 'create table' was defaulting to tempdb and I needed to specify the database name. As others have stated, I checked with my DB access operators to make sure I had create table permissions. Since I had the necessary permissions already, I came up with the solution below.

The following returned the tempdb error:

```
driver={SQL Server};server=YOUR_SERVER_NAME;trusted_connection=true
```

Once I included the database name, the code worked fine. Here is the code that worked for me:

```
driver={SQL Server};server=YOUR_SERVER_NAME;database=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME;trusted_connection=true'
```

I hope this post is helpful!