# CREATE TABLE permission denied in database SQL Server 2008 R2 ApsaraDB for RDS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ddl, create-table

After I created a new Database 'testDB' . 
Using SSMS 2012 I'm getting an error

```
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'testDB'
```

This is My Code

```
USE [testDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employeetempp]
([FirstName] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 [LastName] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And Also adding My Permissions For the DB

```
CREATE VIEW
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE RULE
CREATE DEFAULT
CREATE TYPE
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION
CREATE SCHEMA
CREATE SYNONYM
CREATE AGGREGATE
CREATE QUEUE
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG
CONNECT
CONNECT REPLICATION
CHECKPOINT
SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS
AUTHENTICATE
SHOWPLAN
ALTER ANY SCHEMA
ALTER ANY FULLTEXT CATALOG
SELECT
REFERENCES
EXECUTE
VIEW DATABASE STATE
VIEW DEFINITION
ALTER
CONTROL
```

What can I  do to to obtain permission for creating the table.

I went into the database, security, users, right-click on the user, properties. Membership The 'db_owner' property is checked.

Thanks ,
Nidhin

Comment: Have you Checked the property 'dbcreator ' too?If not, do it and try creating table again.

Comment: @Mohammad i dont see any properties named  'dbcreator' . There is a 'db_ddladmin'  option when im trying to check it gives me a permission error. As the current user doesnt have permission

Comment: @Nidhin go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563565/create-table-permission-denied-in-database-tempdb

Comment: @PRABA i have gone through that link before but it doesnt solve my  issue. Thats why i posted it as a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys as it was solved. The issue was in the server side the memory allocated for my DB server was full. As i cleared some old DBs everything works perfectly now .